# Find all (real) solutions for $x$ in $ 2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2 . $

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

Find all real solutions for $x$ in
$$ 2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2 . $$

Expanding would be a bit messy, but I can't think of any other way.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: $x=0,\pm1$ are trivial solutions.  Furthermore, you can prove with derivatives that they are the only real solutions

Comment: This has to be solved by numerical methods. I doubt if you can solve it by hand.